# Internal data post [Kohana 3.1]

Tags: post, request, kohana, internal

In Kohana 3.1.x framework.

What are the benefits to send data with internal requests like this

```
$post = Request::factory('module/data')
        ->method(Request::POST)
        ->post(array('some' => 'random data'))
        ->execute()
        ->response;
```

if you could simply send data like this

```
Module::instance()->data(array('some' => 'random data'));
```

In this example `Module` is a random module and `data` is some random method.

I'll call this `Module` via ajax and internal requests. I'm planning to design RESTful API.

**QUESTION IS: Why use HMVC instead of just directly using an internal class API**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they're *internal* requests, there is *no additional HTTP request being made*.

You might want to take a look at Request_Client_Internal and compare it to Request_Client_External. After that you should feel enlightened :)

Edit:

You should know that AJAX requests aren't the only "external HTTP requests". cURL, PECL HTTP, file_get_contents() and other PHP functions will also send an external HTTP request (imho you should read the RFC 2616 to understand how HTTP actually works).

Comment: Isn't both of my examples _internal requests_ without additional HTTP request? Surely via Ajax there will be additional HTTP request.

Comment: and Module::instance() is ... what?

Answer (score 0):

With HMVC calls you can use the same controller for both Ajax and internal requests. Also, it can handle a standard (non-ajax) http-requests, form submits for example. All-in-one solution, single entry point.

If you dont want HMVC calls, you will require one call for internal request (somewhere in base controller) and another one - in a special Ajax controller. Also you may have a problems with a data rendering (usually HMVC and ajax calls are using different templates). Its not DRY.

Comment: Isn't `Module::instance()->data(array(...));` also internal request?

Answer (score 0):

I would comment on the above, what biakaveron said, but I can't yet, so I put it as an answer.
@stacknoob: Could you use `Module::instance()->data(array(...))` as controller's action? You could - with some extra code.
Instead, what biakaveron already said, you can keep your code logic and have the action return the same result for AJAX **and** HMVC requests. In one place. DRY + KISS.

Comment: That's a good add! Thanks! I'm finally going to understand the difference. Also I would like to note that there's overhead when using HMVC.

Comment: Maybe this link helps - http://techportal.ibuildings.com/2010/02/22/scaling-web-applications-with-hmvc/